# How to stop a user navigating away in a webbrowser?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently building a webbrowser that only loads one page, but I don't want the user to be able to navigate away by clicking advertisement links, as I don't want them to be able to surf the net, clicking links could eventually lead them back to Google to search for what they like if they are clever enough!

Any ideas?

Comment: If you really only know VB, what exactly has this do to with c++? And what exactly is your question? How to render a web page?

Comment: just got carried away with the tags sorry, and no how to stop a user from navigating away from the site set...

Comment: alert('PLEASE DON'T LEAVE!');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the page is done loading, intercept the links :

```
Dim olink As HtmlElement

Dim olinks As HtmlElementCollection = WB1.Document.Links

For Each olink In olinks

    olink.AttachEventHandler("onclick", AddressOf LinkClicked)

Next
```

Then add a function :

```
Private Sub LinkClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If txtAddress.Enabled = True Then
        Dim link As HtmlElement = WB1.Document.ActiveElement
        Dim url As String = link.GetAttribute("href")
        MsgBox("Link Clicked: " & link.InnerText & vbCrLf & "Destination: " & url)
        WB1.Navigate(url, False)
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like more of a sysadmin issue, to me.

I'm not familiar with any of the proper software. but if you set up the OS so that it will only be allowed to access webpages on a "whitelist", then there will be no need to write a custom web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a browser component in you project, you should add an event listener for your browser URL, if it changed, redirect to your desired page.